# What is the one word which means this?

Tags: single-word-requests

A place where no one lives. It looks mysterious, completely ruined by some sort of event that might have happened in the past. The land is barren. There are some ruined structures. It looks like people used to live in that place many, many years ago but some event(like a war or a disaster) completely destroyed the place and the people left, leaving behind these tombs which became ruins with the passage of time.

Comment: "Wasteland" is another term, though it doesn't carry the connotation of having once been occupied.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the word you are looking for might be ***derelict***.

According to Collins:

[***Derelict***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/derelict):

> *adjective*
>
> 1) deserted or abandoned, as by an owner, occupant, etc
>       2) falling into ruins; neglected; dilapidated
>       3) neglectful of duty or obligation; remiss
>
> *noun*
>
> 1) a person abandoned or neglected by society; a social outcast or vagrant
>       2) property deserted or abandoned by an owner, occupant, etc
>       3) a vessel abandoned at sea
>       4) a person who is neglectful of duty or obligation

Answer (score 1):

*Ghost town*, or possibly *ghost region*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_town

Answer (score 1):

**Desolation**

: the condition of a place or thing that has been damaged in such a way that it is no longer suitable for people to live in : the state or condition of being desolate

http://i.word.com/idictionary/desolation

Answer (score 0):

The word you are looking for is *deserted*. It means that people once lived there but that now it is empty of people.